# return web page contents not the web page name spring boot

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot

I want to display the contents of the HTML page. But this returns the name of the web page. I tried using @controller and @Responsebody also using @RestController. Neither gives the contents of the page. Please help me to solve this problem. I'm trying to display vendors.html, but prints the name "vendors".
This is my code.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/vendors")
public class VendorController {

@Autowired
private VendorService vendorService;

@RequestMapping("/indexVendor")
@ResponseBody
public String viewIndexVendor2(Model model) throws Exception {
List<Vendor> listVendor;

listVendor = vendorService.listAll();
model.addAttribute("listVendor", listVendor);
return "vendors";

}

}
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**@ResponseBody** return the response of the method, in your case a String in the value is "vendors", so your request "/vendors/indexVendor" return "vendors". It is quite normal who should display "vendors".
To display the content of your "vendors.html" page, start by removing the @ResponseBody annotation and rename your page to "vendors.jsp" and configure a templating engine to handle jsp files or use themleaf.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried to generate a jsp file. but still it prints "vendors". I've tried to generate html pages before. But some times it renders the page, sometimes it prints the name of the web page. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: did you remove the @ResponseBody annotation?

Comment: Yes I removed the annotation

Comment: How do you configure your vendors.jsp? note that if your vendors template does not exist, the result displays "vendors". You may need to set up a Tiles.xml system to build your templates using your JSP pages ! Find out earlier how to manage your "webapp" to use a template system.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. As you mentioned it can't find the Vendor.html page, thus displays   "vendors". I got a copy of the project and tried to run the application again, and it successfully displayed vendors.html page . But still I can't find why it couldn't find the web page in the previous project. Because the same web page is in both the projects. Can you find the reason? thanks :)